googlesheets4 writing from R doesn't trigger calculations
I'm using R googlesheets4 to write data using write_sheet, which puts the data correctly in the sheet. However, formulas that depend on the data I write don't recalculate (I can trigger them by going into the web/sheet and rewriting the formula in the cell). How do I trigger this recalculation from R, and without going to each formula and editing it?
The line I use to write into the sheet import is:
write_sheet(estimates, ss, sheet="import")

Thanks
